# HTTP Error 400: Bad Request Python, Google App Engine

Tags: python, json, google-app-engine, http, telegram-bot

I'm writing a Bot for Telegram in Python using Google App Engine.

I want to use an [API](http://rocketplan.rodney.io/) (the Doc (Bottom of the Page) is written in German) to make an Schedule for that I made my HTTP request like this

```
live_event = json.loads(urllib2.urlopen('http://rbtvapi.rodney.io/events').read())
```

For /events it worked fine

but when I tryed the same with http://rbtvapi.rodney.io/api/schedule it returned me an

`HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request`

I'm not so used to python or json so my two questions would be

1. How do I make this request
2. How do I get the content of one element e.g. the title of the first element.

Edit: I already tried to `import requests` or `urllib3` but as it seems Google App Engine doesn't support them

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. `schedule = json.loads(urllib2.urlopen('http://rbtvapi.rodney.io/api/schedule').read())` works just fine from me in a tiny toy GAE app. Please write and post (editing your Q) the tiniest GAE app that gives you this problem (posting much code in comments would be unreadable -- and I don't have an answer beyond "the problem you stated, as you stated it so far, just does not exist" which is not much of an answer:-)

Comment: @AlexMartelli okay I tried the code today again and now it works I didn't change anything but somehow you made it work so thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you to use `requests` library intead of urllib2.

There's an example hope it helps you:

```
import json
import requests
response = requests.get('http://rbtvapi.rodney.io/api/schedule')
live_event = json.loads(response.content)
```

Tested and it works fine :)

To get the titles, you can loop through the json dictionary

```
for event in live_event['schedule']:
    print(event['title'])
```

Comment: The Google App Engine Log gives me this `ImportError: No module named requests`

Comment: If you're under a linux enviroment just this package: pip install requests

Comment: As it seems Google App Engine doesn't support requests I also tried urllib3 but that didn't work either